# Dynamically add element to map after pattern matching match case

Tags: scala, maps, pattern-matching

I have a method as follows:

```
  protected def extract(implicit params:Params) =
    Map(
  "address" -> params.address,
  "city" -> reconcileCity,
  "region" -> params.region,
)collect {
    case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
  }
```

I want to substitute value of city from another method as follows :

```
  protected def reconcileCity(implicit params:Params)
  params.city match {
  case Some("madras") => "Chennai"
  case Some("bangalore") => "Bengaluru"
  case Some("gurgaon") => "Gurugram"
  case _ => params.city.mkString
}
```

But I am getting error like :

```
  Error:(177, 24) value isDefined is not a member of java.io.Serializable
  case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
  Error:(177, 44) value get is not a member of java.io.Serializable
  case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the type of your maps values? Looks like the compiler is inferring `java.io.Serializable` as the common ancestor for all your value types.

Comment: For the below scenario:

          `protected def extract(implicit params:Params) =
         Map(
          "address" -> params.address,
          "city" -> params.city,
          "region" -> params.region,
           )collect {
           case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
          }`
it works fine.Only after I call the generic method `reconcileCity` from method `extract` that I get the error as the type of method `reconcileCity` is Serializable

Answer (score 0):

`isDefined` is a method that exists in `Option` class.
But you're trying to replace Option[String] with String, and call `isDefined` on it.

I'm assuming everything in `params` is an `Option`, so your code should look something like this:

```
protected def reconcileCity(implicit params:Params)
params.city match {
case Some("madras") => Some("Chennai")
  case Some("bangalore") => Some("Bengaluru")
  case Some("gurgaon") => Some("Gurugram")
  case other => other
}
```

Comment: thanks!
any way to handle case sensitivity for this as well.That is I want to handle like:
         `protected def reconcileCity(implicit params:Params)
params.city match {
case Some("madras")or ("Madras") => Some("Chennai")
  case Some("bangalore") or("Bangalore")=> Some("Bengaluru")
  case Some("gurgaon") or ("Gurgaon")=> Some("Gurugram")
  case other => other
}`

Comment: You mean something like:
`case Some(str) if str.toLowerCase() == "madras" => Some("Chennai")`

Comment: I mean it should handle all cases:`"madras","MADRAS","Madras"` etc

Comment: @b1399877 my comment handles all those cases... feel free to try it

Answer (score 0):

Agreed on @Alexey's answer that `isDefined` and `get` are methods that can be applied to `Option` class. Alexay suggested to change all the returning values to `Some` but I suggest to change only the returned value to `Some` as

```
  protected def extract(implicit params:Params) =
    Map(
      "address" -> params.address,
      "city" -> Some(reconcileCity),
      "region" -> params.region
    )collect {
      case (k, v) if v.isDefined => k -> v.get
    }


  protected def reconcileCity(implicit params:Params) = params.city.get match {
    case "madras" | "Madras" => "Chennai"
    case "bangalore" | "Banglore" => "Bengaluru"
    case "gurgaon" | "GurGaon" => "Gurugram"
    case _ => params.city.mkString
  }
```

Comment: what about the case when `params.city` is `None`?
Also, it doesn't handle the case `"MADRAS"` for example, although that wasn't originally part of the question... :-(